Why does a picker in a CollectionView set the SelectedItem binding to null?
I have a picker inside a CollectionView that should select a predefined item ColorNav but when it starts the item is not selected.
XAML:
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Players" />
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding PlayerList}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Player">
                        <SwipeView>
                            <Border>
                                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, *, *" ColumnSpacing="1" >
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                    <Picker Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ColorsPicker, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:MainViewModel}}}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" SelectedItem="{Binding ColorNav}"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ColorNav.Name}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </SwipeView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
            <Button Text="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
        </StackLayout>

C#
    public class Player
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
        public int ColorId { get; set; } = default!;
        public Colour ColorNav { get; set; } = default!;
    }

    public class Colour
    {
        public int ColorId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    }

    public MainViewModel() {
            ColorsPicker = [
                new Colour {
                    ColorId = 1,
                    Name = "Red"
                },
                new Colour {
                    ColorId = 2,
                    Name = "Blue"
                },
                new Colour {
                    ColorId = 3,
                    Name = "Yellow"
                },
            ];

            PlayerList = [
                new Player {
                    Name = "John",
                    ColorId = 1,
                    ColorNav = ColorsPicker[0],
                },
                new Player {
                    Name = "Carla",
                    ColorId = 3,
                    ColorNav = ColorsPicker[2],
                },
            ];
    }

While debugging, I can see that ColorNav is loaded in the BindingContext, but somehow it becomes null when the page starts. When I go to 'Save, ColorNav is null for every player. If I remove SelectedItem="{Binding ColorNav}" from the Picker, ColorNav remains as expected.Every player in the BindingContext has ColorNav initialized

Do you mean ColorNav initialised after the binding?

I initialize ColorNav for each player in the viewmodel before binding it to the picker. I added some context to the question.

Did you implemented OnPropertyChanged in your VM, and using observable collections? Another thing could be the ItemSource of picker is a different list from SelectedItem cause the issue, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaui%5Dpicker+collection

ItemsSource is bound to ObservableCollection<Colour> colorsPicker and ColorNav is a Colour too. As I mentioned, the SelectedItem ColorNav changes to null when the page loads. I believe this happens because it tries to load the SelectedItem before loading the ItemsSource, and not finding anything, it sets it to null.

You can put variable ColorsPicker and variable ColorNav inside of model Player.cs and implement interface INotifyPropertyChanged for model Player.cs.
public class Player: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    public int ColorId { get; set; } = default!;
    // public Colour ColorNav { get; set; } = default!;

    public ObservableCollection<Colour> ColorsPicker { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Colour>();


    //add a property for the SelectedItem property of picker
    private Colour _colorNav;
    public Colour ColorNav
    {
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _colorNav, value);
        }
        get { return _colorNav; }
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

Besides, if we want UI update(<Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ColorNav.Name}") while changing the selected Item of current Picker, we also need to implement interface INotifyPropertyChanged for model Colour.cs
public class Colour: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
    //public string Name { get; set; } = default!;

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _name, value);
        }
        get { return _name; }
    }
    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}

Then we can initialize MainViewModel.cs as follows:
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Colour> ColorsPicker { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Colour>();
    public ObservableCollection<Player> PlayerList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Player>();

    public MainViewModel() {

        ColorsPicker = [
     new Colour {
                ColorId = 1,
                Name = "Red"
            },
            new Colour {
                ColorId = 2,
                Name = "Blue"
            },
            new Colour {
                ColorId = 3,
                Name = "Yellow"
            },
        ];

        PlayerList = [
            new Player {
                Name = "John",
                ColorId = 1,
                ColorNav = ColorsPicker[0],
                ColorsPicker = ColorsPicker // initialize ColorsPicker
            },
            new Player {
                Name = "Carla",
                ColorId = 3,
                ColorNav = ColorsPicker[2],
                ColorsPicker = ColorsPicker // initialize ColorsPicker

            },
        ];

    }
}

And then, we can bind data as follows:
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding PlayerList}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Player">
                <SwipeView>
                    <Border>
                        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, *, *" ColumnSpacing="1" >
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <!--<Picker Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ColorsPicker, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:MainViewModel}}}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" SelectedItem="{Binding ColorNav}"/>-->
                            <Picker Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ColorsPicker}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" SelectedItem="{Binding ColorNav ,Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ColorNav.Name}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </SwipeView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>


Thank you, Jessie. Adding ColorsPicker to each instance of 'Player' resolves the issue, although it seems weird to initialize the same collection for each instance, which might be inefficient (I think), but it works :)
